# How to simplify repetitive jQuery code with different selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have hundreds of lists and they are categorized into more than 30 categories.

What I do is I make the lists display:none, for each category has a click.slideToggle() function, and also slideUp other lists except the list clicked, the problem is I have to write repititive very long codes for each list.

I need someone to suggest me a better way to write these javascript lines, so here are the codes for clearer picture.

```
<span id='categoryA'>
<div id='listA' class='list'>

<span id='categoryB'>
<div id='listB' class='list'>

<span id='categoryC'>
<div id='listC' class='list'>

<span id='categoryD'>
<div id='listD' class='list'>

<!-- there are around 25 more of similar lists -->
```

CSS:

```
.list {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#categoryA").click(function() {
    $("#listA").slideToggle(function() {
      $("#listB,#listC,#listD").slideUp();
    });
  });

   $("#categoryB").click(function() {
    $("#listB").slideToggle(function() {
      $("#listA,#listC,#listD").slideUp();
    });
  });

   $("#categoryC").click(function() {
    $("#listC").slideToggle(function() {
      $("#listA,#listB,#listD").slideUp();
    });
  }); 

   $("#categoryD").click(function() {
    $("#listD").slideToggle(function() {
      $("#listA,#listB,#listC").slideUp();
    });
  });
});
```

The point is I want that every time `#categoryA` is clicked, it slideToggle `#listA`, and if I click `#categoryB`, it slideToggle `#listB` and slideUp any other list that is currently slideDown.

I have more than 30 categories. How do I make the code simpler and more efficient? Does anyone have a smarter way to do this?

Comment: Use classes and one single event handler, then target the elements by position in the DOM.

Comment: BTW there already are *accordion* plugins for jQuery, even an [official one](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) from their jQueryUI widget collection and a ton of 3rd party ones. You might want to check out existing code before you roll your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<span class='category' id='categoryA'>Title A</span>
<div id='listA' class='list'>...</div>

<span class='category' id='categoryB'>Title B</span>
<div id='listB' class='list'>...</div>

<span class='category' id='categoryC'>Title C</span>
<div id='listC' class='list'>...</div>

<span class='category' id='categoryD'>Title D</span>
<div id='listD' class='list'>...</div>
```

and

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".category", function () {
        $(this).next(".list").slideToggle(function () {
            $(".list").not(this).slideUp();
        };
    });
});
```

Remarks:

- Use CSS classes (instead of HTML IDs) to group similar elements. Note how my code does not need IDs *at all*, you could drop them unless you really need them for something else.
- This uses [*event delegation*](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- `.not()` excludes an element from a list in jQuery.
- The `this` inside the "complete" callback of `.slideToggle()` refers to the animated element (consequently, the "complete" callback is called once per animated element, not after all selected elements have finished sliding - something to keep in mind when you animate more than one element at some point)

Comment: Nice! this made my life so much easier, thank you so much for your help.. One more little problem though, I use php multi-dimensional array and echo all the elements, and after every <span class='category> there is a <br> then <div class='list'>, is there a command to skip or ignore the <br>?, if not then I will re-arrange my php code.. Thx in advance

Comment: Just don't include the `<br>` in the first place. `<div>` is a block element, meaning that it breaks the line on its own (use CSS to create margins as necessary). While you *can* modify the jQuery code to deal with virtually any kind of HTML structure, re-structuring your HTML to a different (and most of the time more sensible) form will result in cleaner HTML *and* cleaner jQuery code. So while you could use something like `$(this).nextAll(".list").first()`, just clean up your HTML. (Hint: using a `<span>` for a heading-type item isn't exactly the right choice, either)

Comment: Yup, thank you so much for the knowledge, I already changed my <span> to <div>, was just curious if there is a way to skip an element or something, I still had a lot to learn with jquery. Thx

Comment: Take a moment to read through the ["traversing" part of the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

Comment: Thx for the link! will read through it, I usually read my reference from w3schools.com, easier to understand, but I guess it's not as complete.

Comment: Most people with a bit of experience will heartily dis-recommend using w3schools as a source of reference for anything. They have built quite a reputation of being incorrect and/or incomplete, depending on the topic, and overly spammy \*cough\* *search-engine optimized* on top of that. And especially jQuery's docs are good enough to read without 3rd party help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty simple function that uses [`jQuery.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to delegate events and the [`.next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) functions to filter the selection when a user clicks a trigger.

```
/**
* @param [jQuery] $obj - the jQuery selection we want to accordionize
* @param [Object] opt  - optional settings
* @return [jQuery] $obj
*/
function accordionize($obj, opt){
    opt = $.extend({
        triggers: 'dt',
        content: 'dd'
    }, opt || {});

    // bind the click events to all elements that match our trigger selection
    $obj.on('click', opt.triggers, function(e){
        // Get the associated content element
        var $target = $(this).next(opt.content);
        $target.slideDown(function(){
            $obj.find(opt.content).not($target).slideUp();
        });    
    });
    // Create a custom event to setup accordion.
    // hides all content elements except the first.
    $obj.on('accordionize.reset', function(){
        $obj.find(opt.content).hide().first().show();
    });

    return $obj.trigger('accordionize.reset');
}
```

It requires that you wrap the content in a element:

```
<dl class="accordion">
    <dt>Topic One</dt>
    <dd>Ipsum loren</dd>
    <dt>Topic two</dt>
    <dd>Some fun facts about topic two</dd>
    <dt>Topic three</dt>
    <dd>Some fun facts about topic three</dd>
</dl>

<div class="accordion">
    <h3 class="trigger">Topic One</h3>
    <div class="content">Ipsum loren</div>
    <h3 class="trigger">Topic two</h3>
    <div class="content">Some fun facts about topic two</div>
    <h3 class="trigger">Topic three</h3>
    <div class="content">Some fun facts about topic three</div>
</div>
```

The first example uses a [description list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) which a pretty good fit for a list of categories.

And call the function like so:

```
accordionize($('dl.accordion'));
accordionize($('div.accordion'), {
  triggers: '.trigger',
  content: '.content'
});
```

Comment: You can try it out and view the specs at http://jsfiddle.net/maxcal/fqgcwoja/6/. (I wrote this as an answer for the question, I'm not pushing a private project)

Comment: +1 for showing how to extend the basic functionality (though I'd argue that writing an entire jQuery plugin is slightly out of scope for this kind of problem). Not sure what your *"not pushing a private project"* disclaimer means, however...

Comment: I can agree that it's a little overkill, but I wanted to show that separating functionality and DOM structure can be a really good thing. "not pushing a private project" - I just didn't want to give the impression that this was a plug for yet another jQuery accordion plugin.

Comment: Oh, all right. I guess mentioning that there already are elaborate plugins that solve the OP's very problem would be a good thing.

Comment: I would - if I knew of a jQuery accordion plugin that I would recommend to anybody except my worst enemy :)

Comment: I guess there must be a usable one out there, somewhere. Since the OP's original problem is so small-scale, writing 3 lines of code that do exactly that seems like an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let use this.

```
html :

<span id='A' class="category">
<div id='listA' class='list'>

<span id='B'class="category">
<div id='listB' class='list'>

<span id='C'class="category">
<div id='listC' class='list'>

<span id='D' class="category">
<div id='listD' class='list'>

//there are around 25 more of similar lists//

css :

.list {
    display: none;
}

javascript :

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".category").click(function(){
      id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
      $(".list").slideUp();
      $("#list"+id).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Hope this works as you expected..

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that whenever category is clicked, corresponding list is sliding down and other lists from categories are sliding up. If that is the case then whenever any category is clicked, then slide up all the lists and slide down only the list which is belonged to category.

```
$(".category").click(function(){
      $(".list).slideUp();
      $(this).find('.list').slideDown();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out something like this

```
 $("span").on("click", function(){
  var that = $(this)
  that.slidToggle(function(){
  $("#listA,#listC,#listD").slideUp();});
```

});